# Does JBoss 5.1.0 supports hot deployment ? If yes, how can I do it?

Tags: eclipse, jboss5.x

I am a beginner in JBoss. I just want to know how to **hot deploy** my web applications on JBoss 5.1.0.
1. In eclipse.
2. Without Eclipse.

I am using windows XP.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1a) For Eclipse you can either configure the usual WebToolsPlatform (WTP) to do hot deployments.

1b) You can install the JBoss Tools from http://www.jboss.org/tools which might some things smoother. You can think of it as an extension of WTP.

1c) Use a small Ant-Skript to do the same as 2)

2) Simply copy your war file into the subdirectory `server/default/deploy`.